# как сделать активный элемент навбара

Tags: javascript, css, html5

```
<ul class="nav-box">
                    <li class="nav-list">Home</li>
                    <li class="nav-list">About me</li>
                    <li class="nav-list">Porfolio</li>
                    <li class="nav-list">Contact</li>
                </ul>


//---
```

---------js------------

```
navItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        console.log(index)
        if(item.classList.contains('active')){
            item.classList.remove('active')
        }else{
            item[index].classList.add('active')        
        }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let navItems = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-list');

navItems.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', function(event){
        navItems.forEach(el => {
            el.classList.remove('active');
        });
        
        this.classList.add('active');
    })
})
```

```css
.active { background: blue; color: white; }
```

```html
<ul class="nav-box">
                    <li class="nav-list">Home</li>
                    <li class="nav-list">About me</li>
                    <li class="nav-list">Porfolio</li>
                    <li class="nav-list">Contact</li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: Как вы относитесь к такой практике, что в данном случае можно не проходить по всем элементам, а напрямую обратиться к элементу с классом 'active', и удалить этот класс ?

Comment: Каким образом?.

Comment: document.querySelector('.nav-list.active')?.classList.remove('active');

Comment: А, ну можно, да.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="nav-box">
   <li class="nav-list">Home</li>
   <li class="nav-list" onclick="openCity(event, 'About me')" id="defaultOpen">About me</li>
   <li class="nav-list">Porfolio</li>
   <li class="nav-list">Contact</li>
</ul>

<script>
    document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```